# Oracle Stored Procedure variables not working/invalid table name

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm writing a stored procedure to insert data from an intermediate table into another table. I am using a dynamic sql statement because I have to add the argument variables in because this will be used for multiple tables/different data. I am new to plsql and this is really my first go at writing a stored procedure. It works perfectly when i hard code in values. I try adding my Database and Table variables in by concatenating them in the first insert line and i get the error:

```
ORA-00903: invalid table name
ORA-06512: at "ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT", line 29
ORA -06512: at line 14
```

Any suggestions?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT (
    P_SOURCE_DB      IN VARCHAR2,
    P_SOURCE_TABLE   IN VARCHAR2,
    P_TARGET_DB      IN VARCHAR2,
    P_TARGET_TABLE   IN VARCHAR2,
    P_COLUMN_NAME    IN VARCHAR2)
AS
    l_sql_statement   VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
    l_sql_statement := '
        INSERT INTO ' || P_TARGET_DB || '.' || P_TARGET_TABLE || '
                   (PKEY_SRC_OBJECT,
                    VERSION_SEQ,
                    TIMELINE_ACTION,
                    LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                    SRC_ROWID,
                    HUB_STATE_IND,
                    ROLE_TP)
            SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT,
                   1              AS VERSION_SEQ,
                   0              AS TIMELINE_ACTION,
                   INSERT_TS      AS LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                   ''3''          AS "SRC_ROWID",
                   1              AS "HUB_STATE_IND",
                   MISSING_VALUES AS ROLE_TP
              FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate
             WHERE COLUMN_NM = :COLUMN_NAME
               AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM = :TARGET_TABLE';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_sql_statement);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_statement USING P_COLUMN_NAME, P_TARGET_TABLE;

    COMMIT;
END;
```

This is a hardcoded version that works 100% fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT (
    P_SOURCE_DB      IN VARCHAR2,
    P_SOURCE_TABLE   IN VARCHAR2,
    P_TARGET_DB      IN VARCHAR2,
    P_TARGET_TABLE   IN VARCHAR2,
    P_COLUMN_NAME    IN VARCHAR2)
AS
    l_sql_statement   VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
    l_sql_statement varchar2(4000) := '
        INSERT INTO ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP' || '
                   (PKEY_SRC_OBJECT,
                    VERSION_SEQ,
                    TIMELINE_ACTION,
                    LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                    SRC_ROWID,
                    HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP)
             SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT,
                    1              AS VERSION_SEQ,
                    0              AS TIMELINE_ACTION,
                    INSERT_TS      AS LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                    ''3''          AS "SRC_ROWID",
                    1              AS "HUB_STATE_IND",
                    MISSING_VALUES AS ROLE_TP
               FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate
              WHERE COLUMN_NM = ''ROLE_TP''
                AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM = ''C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP''';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_sql_statement);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_statement;

    COMMIT;
END;
```

This is the code I am using to call the procedure:

```
DECLARE
    P_SOURCE_DB      VARCHAR2 (200);
    P_SOURCE_TABLE   VARCHAR2 (200);
    P_TARGET_DB      VARCHAR2 (200);
    P_TARGET_TABLE   VARCHAR2 (200);
    P_COLUMN_NAME    VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
    P_SOURCE_DB := NULL;
    P_SOURCE_TABLE := NULL;
    P_TARGET_DB := NULL;
    P_TARGET_TABLE := NULL;
    P_COLUMN_NAME := NULL;

    ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT (
        P_SOURCE_DB      => ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID,
        P_SOURCE_TABLE   => Ref_Intermediate,
        P_TARGET_DB      => ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID,
        P_TARGET_TABLE   => C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP,
        P_COLUMN_NAME    => ROLE_TP);
--rollback;
END;
```

Comment: By default, stored procedures have definer's rights. Which means, the only privileges available when executing the procedure are those granted to the user who created the procedure in the first place; and, moreover, only those privileges granted to that user DIRECTLY (not via a role) are available. In your case, if you (or whoever wrote the procedure, really) can access the offending table, ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT, in a plain SQL statement, but not through a stored procedure, that likely means that "you" have access to the table through a privilege granted to a role you have.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. I'm an intern working on this project. i wrote the stored procedure but I don't have access add it to the database so a higher up had to do that. Now I'm trying to make it dynamic. If you're telling me it's some sort of privilege issue, then why does it work when I hardcode in values?

Comment: Can you show the code that does work?  Are they both installed in the same Schema of the same DB?

Comment: Can you also include the code you are using to call the procedure? I suspect you're passing the arguments in the wrong order, or more likely the `P_TARGET_DB` is null. (That's the target schema, not a DB, which is slightly confusing but not relevant *8-)

Comment: I added a hardcoded version that works perfectly and inserts into the table as expected. They are both in the same schema yes. I have also included the code I am using to call the procedure. @AlexPoole You're right it is a schema. Sorry for calling it a DB, its just kinda how we refer to it in the workplace. It's a schema that is generally used to store tables and procedures for certain data.

Comment: "You" (as the user) can have privileges to a table in another schema either because such privileges were granted directly to your username, or because they were granted to a role (for example, your DBA may have created the role INTERNS) and you were granted that role. Both kinds of privileges will apply if you execute a SQL statement, or also an anonymous PL/SQL block. But only the first kind of privileges (granted directly) apply if you write a **stored** procedure. Are you saying you hard-coded the schema and table name, then you called the **stored** procedure and it worked?

Comment: That can't be using exactly that call, you're using variables that don't exist; so at best you've somehow left out the quotes. Copy and paste in exactly what you are really running.

Comment: @mathguy yes that is what i am saying, i edited and included the hardcoded version that works perfectly. I am trying to make the procedure dynamic and use the same schema and table that i used in the hardcoded version

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm confused now. Everything that I pasted is what I am running. What variables am I using that don't exist?

Comment: The privileges don't seem to be the issue here; the anonymous block is just calling the procedure, and the procedure uses the same rules whether the names are hard-coded or passed in. More importantly, the error is "invalid table name", not the "table or view does not exist" you'd see from a privilege issue. I still think it isn't getting the `TARGET_DB` value you think it is, so it is trying to reference a table name starting with a period.

Comment: @AlexPoole - I noticed that and I deleted my comment. And yes, you are right about the text of the error message.

Comment: @TheManC - you showed things like `P_SOURCE_DB => ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID`. What is `ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID`? It isn't a string literal as it isn't enclosed in single quotes. So you seem to be editing what you posted?

Comment: Where you show the working stored procedure with hard-coded names, you are showing a DIFFERENT table, **C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP**, not the one that gave you the error, **LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT**. Did you try to hard-code THAT name? What you show right now for the hard-coded version is irrelevant to the question you asked.

Comment: @mathguy - `LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT` is the procedure name, not the invalid table name. The error is coming from line 29 of that procedure, which is the `execute immediate` call, and that gets the ORA-00903.

Comment: That's exactly how I have it when I'm calling it is what I have pasted. ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID is the schema for the tables. I just dont have the variables called in the hardcoded version.

Comment: @TheManC - what you have shown in yoru anonymous block will get `PLS-00201: identifier 'ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID' must be declared`. As in [this db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7c9df83a3be2a27252209a645788070f).

Comment: @mathguy What Alex said is correct. The only thing i changed between the version giving me the error is that I am trying to call P_TARGET_DB and P_TARGET_TABLE

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm not really sure what to say. I just ran what I have pasted without single quotes about 10 times as we've been talking. It runs fine both with and without the single quotes, I just tested. I tried adding the single quotes in the version where I'm calling the variables and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Ugh... forget me! I can't read anymore.

Comment: @AlexPoole You were right. It was passing null in because I was calling with the wrong code so basically I'm an idiot. Thank you for the help though. I appreciate your time.

Comment: We've all been there...

Comment: One of the first indications of someone **not** being an idiot is when they call themselves an idiot... (I should know, I do it all the time!)  :)